# Python3: Checking if a key word within a dictionary matches any part of a string

Tags: list, python-3.x, dictionary, tuples, filenames

I'm having trouble converting my working code from lists to dictionaries. The basics of the code checks a file name for any keywords within the list.

But I'm having a tough time understanding dictionaries to convert it. I am trying to pull the name of each key and compare it to the file name like I did with lists and tuples. Here is a mock version of what i was doing.

```
fname = "../crazyfdsfd/fds/ss/rabbit.txt"
hollow = "SFV"
blank = "2008"
empty = "bender"

# things is list
things = ["sheep", "goat", "rabbit"]
# other is tuple
other = ("sheep", "goat", "rabbit")
#stuff is dictionary
stuff = {"sheep": 2, "goat": 5, "rabbit": 6}

try:
    print(type(things), "things")
    for i in things:
        if i in fname:
        hollow = str(i)
        print(hollow)
        if hollow == things[2]:
            print("PERFECT")
except:
    print("c-c-c-combo breaker")

print("\n \n")
try:
    print(type(other), "other")
    for i in other:
        if i in fname:
            blank = str(i)
            print(blank)
            if blank == other[2]:
                print("Yes. You. Can.")
except:
    print("THANKS OBAMA")

print("\n \n")
try:
    print(type(stuff), "stuff")
    for i in stuff:               # problem loop
        if i in fname:
            empty = str(i)
            print(empty)
            if empty == stuff[2]: # problem line
                print("Shut up and take my money!")
except:
    print("CURSE YOU ZOIDBERG!")
```

I am able to get a full run though the first two examples, but I cannot get the dictionary to run without its exception. The loop is not converting empty into  stuff[2]'s value. Leaving money regrettably in fry's pocket. Let me know if my example isn't clear enough for what I am asking. The dictionary is just short cutting counting lists and adding files to other variables.

Comment: in that last `try` block, you may be wanting to assign instead of check for equality? i think `empty == str(i)` should be `empty = str(i)`. that's not the main problem, but something to consider

Comment: I'm not really clear on what your goal is, but one thing, `fname` is only a string, but `if i in fname:` seems to wanting to check if `i` is in the file `fname` contents. and maybe the main problem with the dictionary behavior is that, you know dictionaries are two part: `keys', and `values`, and you seem to be comparing keywords to the dictionary `keys`, so use `for i in stuff.keys():`, and `if empty == stuff.keys()[2]:`

Comment: So what worked for me is changing the entire last `try` block to this: `try:
    print(type(stuff), "stuff")
    for i in stuff.keys():         # problem loop
        if i in open(fname).read():
            empty = str(i)
            print('empty ' + empty)
            if empty == stuff.keys()[2]: # problem line
                print("Shut up and take my money!")`

Comment: or just see the answer below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) is an unordered collection that maps keys to values.  If you define `stuff` to be:

```
stuff = {"sheep": 2, "goat": 5, "rabbit": 6}
```

You can refer to its elements with:

```
stuff['sheep'], stuff['goat'], stuff['rabbit']
```

`stuff[2]` will result in a KeyError, because the key `2` is not found in your dictionary.  You can't compare a string with the last or 3rd value of a dictionary, because the dictionary is not stored in an ordered sequence (the internal ordering is based on hashing).  Use a list or tuple for an ordered sequence - if you need to compare to the last item.

If you want to traverse a dictionary, you can use this as a template:

```
for k, v in stuff.items():
    if k == 'rabbit':
        # do something  - k will be 'rabbit' and v will be 6
```

If you want to check to check the keys in a dictionary to see if they match part of a string:

```
for k in stuff.keys():
    if k in fname:
        print('found', k)
```

Some other notes:

The KeyError would be much easier to notice... if you took out your `try/except` blocks.  Hiding python errors from end-users can be useful.  Hiding that information from YOU is a bad idea - especially when you're debugging an initial pass at code.

You can compare to the last item in a list or tuple with:
`if hollow == things[-1]:`
if that is what you're trying to do.

In your last loop: `empty == str(i)` needs to be `empty = str(i)`.

Comment: do you mean `for k, v in stuff.items()`?

Comment: also `dict`s are iterable, iteration is over the keys so `for k in stuff.keys()` is the same as `for k in stuff`